# backbone - preventing same view from overlapping

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Let say a each row in a table got its own view and a model (CollectionViews). Each row got a button for editing the row data. When clicked an EditView is activated for the current row and model where a form is presented to the user with textfield and cancel and submit button.

[image]

The edit view can only be removed if the user submit the edit form or cancel the edit.

***My question is what is the best way to prevent multiple edit view overlapping*** for example when a user click the edit button, not doing the editing or closing the edit view, and instead click the edit button on another row and another row, without completing the editing.

I just started learning backbone, so this is what I do - which is more of a hack.

```
//create global array for storing view
var editTaskViewArray = new Array();
```

code for when creating the edit view

```
//delete previous view
for (x in editTaskViewArray) {
   editTaskViewArray[x].remove();
}

//empty array
editTaskViewArray = [];

//create and activate edit view
var editTaskView = new App.Views.EditTask({ 
   model: this.model 
}).render();
$('#edittask').append(editTaskView.el).hide().fadeIn(500);

//add edit view to array so that can be removed later
editTaskViewArray.push(editTaskView);
```

Thank you for any tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//change the delete code to.

```
//editTaskView is global
//delete previous view if one exists

If(editTaskView.el){
    editTaskView.remove();
}

//create and activate edit view
editTaskView = new App.Views.EditTask({model:this.model }).render();

$('#editTaskView').append(editTaskView.el).hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution,whenever a view is activated, disable all links to make the current view a modal view, for example all the links in the row is using class for example .delete and .edit. This way, all other views can only be activated only if user close the current view

```
<td><a class='delete' href='#'>Delete</a></td> \
<td><a class='edit' href='#'>Edit</a></td>";
```

use this code to disable the link and disable the events by changing the class name

```
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a" ).removeAttr("href");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.delete" ).attr("class", "nodelete");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.edit" ).attr("class", "noedit");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.nodelete" ).css("opacity", "0.6");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.noedit" ).css("opacity", "0.6");
```

use this code to enable link

```
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a" ).attr("href", "#");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.nodelete" ).attr("class", "delete");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.noedit" ).attr("class", "edit");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.delete" ).css("opacity", "1");
$( "#tbl1" ).find( "a.edit" ).css("opacity", "1");
```